# retrieving date of system boot with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I use the command :

```
who -b
```

to get the date of the last system boot. I work with two different system, Debian and Centos, and the result is different according to the OS.

In Centos :

```
system boot  Oct  6 16:48
```

In Debian (french) :

```
démarrage système 2014-10-07 15:51
```

I'd like to retrieve only the date part.

What I expect :

```
Oct  6 16:48
```

Or

```
2014-10-07 15:51
```

For this, I use "sed", but I cannot find the right regex.
What I have for the moment is :

```
who -b | sed -e 's/[\t a-zA-Z]*//'
```

This command works for Debian because it seems to remove all alphabetic characters and keeps only numerics.
But how to make it work with Centos, where the month is also alphabetic ?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: What's your expected output for both inputs?

Comment: Why don't you say `LANG=en who -b` for the French one?

Comment: Hi, updated my post with what I expect as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your locale to another language just for this specific command: `LANG=xxx command`.

I have a French output too if I don't set `LANG`.

So :

```
$ LANG=C who -b | awk -F'boot *' '{print $2}'
Nov  2 14:19
```

or :

```
$ LANG=C who -b | sed 's/.*boot\s*//'
Nov  2 14:19
```